# Xcode Text Lagging - SourceKitService using 200%+ of CPU

Tags: xcode

I tried Clearing the derived data, restarting the computer, restarting Xcode. This didn't happen my entire time working on this project until a few days ago. It should not be my computer because i just bought a brand new fully loaded Retina MBP 13" a few weeks ago.

Why is the text lagging and how is it possible to surpass 200% CPU usage? The fans don't turn on and it doesn't heat up so something isn't right about that number but it's straight from activity monitor.

I've also been receiving the SourceKitCrashed alerts inside of Xcode

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: I just ended up separating my code putting 1000 line of code per file and its running a lot smoother, it sucks but it works.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I guess Apple wants us all to buy faster computers... lol

Comment: well i have the fastest 13" macbook pro money can buy, you'd think it would run flawlessly